# Query for checking user defined data type in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

What's the query for checking data type is user_defined or not in oracle?

Comment: Please [edit] your question with a [MRE] including examples of the sort of things you want to check. Do you want to determine whether a column of a table contains a user-defined data type or do you want to determine if a PL/SQL variable is of a user-defined data type or is it something else?

Comment: Thanks, I want to determine if a PL/SQL variable is of a user-defined data type or is it something else?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/47037208/1509264